# How to generate a selection list from the results of a previous command and set the answer to a variable

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm attempting to create an onboarding script to automate the AD account creation process. Within the script I would like to use the command `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "\*"'` to get a list of all OUs, then generate a selection list within the PowerShell script to go with the names of each OU. Once the name is selected I would like to set a variable equal to that OUs distinguishedname. Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Okay, on my computer. Can you provide the output of `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "\*"'` in your post? Would just need the property name you want to make a selection out of. **EDIT**: Actually, does [this answer your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71387685/14903754)?

Comment: I would recommend you to use either distinguished name or canonical name since there can be multiple ous with the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Out-GridView`](https://www.google.com/search?q=out-gridview&oq=out-gridview&aqs=chrome..69i57.2624j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with the `-PassThru` switch to allow the, not sure if *"the best way"* but is an easy and friendly alternative.

```
$ous = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "\*"'
$choice = $ous | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName | Out-GridView -PassThru
if($choice) { # if the user selected an item from the DGV and pressed `OK`
    $choice.DistinguishedName
}
else { # user clicked `Cancel` or closed the DGV
    exit
}
```